# Use of command pipeline with open command

Tags: tcl, pipeline

I was trying to understand the usage of command pipeline with the open command in TCL.
I read the following paragraph from the documentation :

" If write-only access is used (e.g. access is w), then standard output for the pipeline is directed to the current standard output unless overridden by the command. If read-only access is used (e.g. access is r), standard input for the pipeline is taken from the current standard input unless overridden by the command. "

I was unable to understand what it means , so i tried some code which was :

```
set f1 [open "| touch testFile.txt" w+]                                      
set a {USA UK AUS IND JAP}
foreach country $a {
       puts $f1 "Member of democratic alliance : $country"
}
close $f1
```

But when i checked the contents of file, there was nothing present.
Can somebody please explain that paragraph from the TCL documentation (with some exaples) and also point where am I doing mistake in my own

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `touch` program does not read its standard input or normally write to its standard output. It just updates the access time of the file, creating it (as a zero length file) if necessary. If you provide standard input to it, it'll just ignore it.

For the purposes of learning about working with pipelines, you might instead prefer to use the `tee` program.

---

Although you haven't got there yet, with a bidirectional pipe (such as those made when you open them with the `w+` mode) you need to be careful because of the potential for deadlock when both sides fill up their OS-level write buffers in the pipe and aren't reading from them. It's usually wisest to switch bidirectional pipes to non-blocking in Tcl. It probably is also a good idea to set them as no stricter than line buffered, or maybe even unbuffered. Or to use `flush` at the right times, but that's harder to get right.

```
fconfigure $f1 -blocking false -buffering none
```

These are fundamental issues caused by needing to have several programs work together, not by pipes themselves or the programming languages used; it's just that bidirectional pipelines are the place where programmers usually first observe them. They very much also apply to working with TCP sockets.

Comment: Thanks Donal
Can you please explain what that paragraph frok the documentation mean